# iText licensing- Do i need to purchase it for my paid app on Google

Tags: android, itext

This might be duplicate but i am just looking for a simple answer which is very hard to find. I am a small developer who has an app that creates pdf report. I am selling this app on Google Play store. As of right now i don't have iText but may be implementing it in my app. I wanted to know if I need to have a license in order to use it in my app and if yes which type. I don't have much knowledge about the type of license there are. Can i use iText for free as i am not a corporation. Please assist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes.

From http://itextpdf.com/purchase (as on November 11th, 2014):

> Although iText is a free/open source software (F/OSS) project, giving
>   you a lot of freedom and flexibility, this doesn't mean you're free to
>   do anything you want. You have to respect the [Affero General Public
>   License (AGPL)](http://itextpdf.com/agpl)...
>
> ... Buying a commercial license is mandatory as soon as you begin
>   commercial activities including distribution of iText software inside
>   your product or deploying it on a network without disclosing the
>   source code of your own applications under the AGPL license. These
>   activities include but are not limited to offering paid services to
>   customers as a SaaS, serving PDFs on the fly in the cloud or in a web
>   application, or shipping iText with a closed source product.

License for iTextG, a port of iText that can be used on Android and GAE is provided in a per-device basis. More info can be found [here](http://itextpdf.com/pricing/android_license).

Answer (score 1):

[iTextG](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextg/) is licenced under [AGPL](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Affero_General_Public_License)

- **No** if your (commercial) App is/will be licensed under AGPL, too
- **Yes** if you don't publish your code under AGPL

Hint:
[Others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863765/itext-license-to-an-android-application) succeeded in running the LGPL/MPL iText version on Android without a problem.